# Arduino code combination - combine temp sensor and buzzer at max min temp codes

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno

I love this site. Thank you all for what you do here!

I am finally getting into doing my own projects with Arduino Uno. I find I learn best when I just do it. I found a tutorial on getting temperature from my TMP36GZ to read out on my 16x2 LCD via Ardino. Way cool! But now, I want to figure out how to make a CEM1203(42) buzzer go off when the temperature hits a maximum and/or minimum. I found a simple code to get the buzzer to go too. Now I just need to combine the two.

Below are the 2 codes. I would like to, say, have the buzzer sound when temp is =/<65°F and =/>75°F.

Thank you for any help you can offer. I'm very excited to be learning this stuff!

```css
/*
 Piezo
 
 This example shows how to run a Piezo Buzzer on pin 9
 using the analogWrite() function.
 
 It beeps 3 times fast at startup, waits a second then beeps continuously
 at a slower pace
 
 */

void setup()  { 
  // declare pin 9 to be an output:
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  beep(50);
  beep(50);
  beep(50);
  delay(1000);
} 

void loop()  { 
  beep(200); 
}

void beep(unsigned char delayms){
  analogWrite(9, 20);      // Almost any value can be used except 0 and 255
                           // experiment to get the best tone
  delay(delayms);          // wait for a delayms ms
  analogWrite(9, 0);       // 0 turns it off
  delay(delayms);          // wait for a delayms ms   
}
```

```html
/*
September 12 2013
October 25 2012
Based off of a project by DJ Mentzik.
Enhanced and modified by WWC and citin.
Supporting documents can be found at http://www.instructables.com/member/WWC/
Use and modife as needed.

Displays Current, 8 sec Average, Max and Min Temperature.

To wire your LCD screen to your Arduino, connect the following pins:
LCD Pin 6 to digital pin 12
LCD Pin 4 to digital pin 11
LCD Pin 11 to digital pin 5
LCD Pin 12 to digital pin 4
LCD Pin 13 to digital pin 3
LCD Pin 14 to digital pin 2
LCD PIN 15 to  POS
LCD PIN 16 to GND


*/

#include <LiquidCrystal.h>                                       // include the LCD driver library

                                                                 //declare variables
float tempC = 0;                                                 // Variable for holding Celcius temp (floating for decimal points precision)
float tempf = 0;                                                 // variable for holding Fareghneit temp
int tempPin = 0;                                                 // Declaring the Analog input to be 0 (A0) of Arduino board.
float samples[8];                                                // Array to hold 8 samples for Average temp calculation
float maxi = 0,mini = 100;                                       // Max/Min temperature variables with initial values. LM35 in simple setup only measures Temp above 0.
int i;

                                             
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);                          // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);                                             // Opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps

lcd.begin(16, 2);                                               // Set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:

lcd.setCursor(2, 0);                                            // Set LCD cursor position (column, row)
lcd.print("Waynes World");                                      // Print text to LCD
lcd.setCursor(3, 1);                                            // Set LCD cursor position (column,row) 
lcd.print("Thermometer");                                       // Print text to LCD
delay(5000); // wait 500ms                                      // Delay to read text
lcd.clear(); // clear LCD display                               // Clear the display
lcd.setCursor(2, 0);                                            // Set LCD cursor position (column, row)
lcd.print("LCD Displayed");                                     // Print text to LCD
lcd.setCursor(1, 1);                                            // Set LCD cursor position (column, row) 
lcd.print(" Averaged Temp ");                                   // Print text to LCD                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
delay(5000);                                                    // Delay to read text
lcd.clear();                                                    // Clear LCD


}

void loop()
{
Serial.println("");                                            // Blank line for spacing in the serial monitor
Serial.println("You are looking at a project built by WWC.");  // Print text to Serial monitor
Serial.print("Feal free to use and modife as needed.");
Serial.println("");                                            // Blank line for spacing in the serial monitor
Serial.print("LM35 Raw data: ");                               // Print text to Serial monitor 
Serial.println(analogRead(tempPin));                           // Displays on serial monitor the sampled value before conversion to real Temperature reading
 
                                                               // Start of calculations FOR loop.
for(i = 0;i<=7;i++){                                           // gets 8 samples of temperature
samples[i] = ( 4.4 * analogRead(tempPin) * 26) / 1024.0;    // conversion math of tmp36GZ sample to readable temperature and stores result to samples array. 

                                                             
                                                                                                                            
                                                             
Serial.println(samples[i]);                                    // Print samples [i] to sertiual monitor                                            
                                                                                                                        
                                                               // ( LCD note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
lcd.setCursor(0, 0);                                           // Set LCD cursor position (column 0, row 0)
lcd.print("Current Temp is: ");                                // Print text to LCD
lcd.setCursor(1, 1);                                           // Set LCD cursor position (column 1, row 1)
lcd.print("  Celcius   ");                                     // Print text to LCD
lcd.setCursor(12, 1);                                          // Set LCD cursor position (column 12, row 1)
lcd.print(samples[i]);                                         // print current Temp sample to LCD
tempC = tempC + samples[i];                                    // do the addition for average temperature
delay(800);                                                    // wait 800ms

}                                                              // END of FOR loop

Serial.println("");                                            // Blank line for spacing in the serial monitor
Serial.println("");                                            // Blank line for spacing in the serial monitor
tempC = tempC/8.0;                                             // calculated the averare of 8 samples in Celcius

tempf = (tempC * 9)/ 5 + 32;                                   // converts to fahrenheit

if(tempC > maxi) {maxi = tempC;}                               // set max temperature
if(tempC < mini) {mini = tempC;}                               // set min temperature
if(tempC >16.0) 

                                                               // Send Results to Serial Monitor
Serial.println("New measurement:");
Serial.print(" Average Temperature in Celcius is " );          // Print text to Serial monitor
Serial.println(tempC);//send the data to the computer          // Send the data to the computer
Serial.print(" Average Temperature in Farenait is " );         // Print text to Serial monitor
Serial.println(tempf);//send the data to the computer          // Send the data to the computer
Serial.print(" MAX Temperature in Celcius is " );              // Print text to Serial monitor
Serial.println(maxi);//send the data to the computer           // Send the data to the computer
Serial.print(" MIN Temperature in Celcius is " );              // Print text to Serial monitor
Serial.println(mini);//send the data to the computer           // Send the data to the computer
                                                          // Send results to LCD.
lcd.setCursor(0, 1);                                           // Set LCD cursor position (column 0, line 1)
lcd.print(" Fahrenheit ");                                     // Print text to LCD
lcd.setCursor(12, 1);                                          // Set LCD cursor position (column 12, line 1)
lcd.print(tempf);                                              // Send the data to the LCD

delay(6000);                                                   // Wait 3 seconds to display the Fahrenheit temp and 3 seconds to display results to LCD screen befor starting the loop again = 6 seconds.
tempC = 0;                                                     // Set tempC to 0 so calculations can be done again
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your temperature code has the most in it so put the additions in there.

Usually you would transfer all from setup. In this case:

```
pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
```

is the only required code. You can put in the rest if you want it to beep on startup.

Transfer over the entire "void beep()" function. So you can call it the same way it is called in the "void loop()" function.

Then in your temp code after tempf is calculated in the line:

```
tempf = (tempC * 9)/ 5 + 32;
```

Put some code like:

```
if (tempf <= 65){

    //low temp beep code here

}
else if (tempf >= 75) {

    //high temp beep code here

}
```